# d3 choropleth queue and fill issues

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, choropleth

I have two different problems but they may be related:

1. I cannot get d3.queue to work if I call a callback function while loading one of the two json files at the same time. If I do not use d3.queue and just nest one d3.json inside another, the maps shows up but the fill issue (explained below) is still not resolved.
2. With or without d3.queue, I cannot get each U.S. state show it's own fill colors. I believe this is because I am failing to create separate "containers" for each state. When I hover over the "path class = states" containers in the browser inspector, the entire map gets highlighted and not individual states as is supposed to. Hence all the colors are being applied on top of each other but the darkest shade dominates and only that one can be seen.

This is the version with d3.queue

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Choropleth Map</title>
<style>

.counties {
  fill: none;
}

.states {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 10, right: 200, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;    
    
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");    
    
var earnings = d3.map();

var path = d3.geo.path();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .rangeRound([600, 860]);

var color = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain(d3.range(2, 10))
.range(['#f7fcfd','#e5f5f9','#ccece6','#99d8c9','#66c2a4','#41ae76','#238b45','#006d2c','#00441b']);

// Load data
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "median_earnings.json", loadjson) //removing loadjson from here brings up the map of U.S. states without any fill. Keeping it shows a blank page
    .await(ready);

function loadjson (error, earnings) {
    if (error) throw error;
    earnings.forEach(function(d) {
            d.id = +d.id;
            d.median = +d.median_earnings;
    });    
}
    
function ready(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "states")    
        .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states), function(a, b) { return a !== b; })
        .attr("d", path);
    
        svg.selectAll("path")
        .attr("class", "states")    
        .datum(earnings)    
        .attr("fill", function(d,i) { 
            return color(d[i].median);
            });
}

        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The us.json file I am using is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lom6io3jswss1bfwizm1n/us.json?dl=0&oref=e&r=AAXXQatp6wESFiF4i3HyOMl1VYEb5LfbHEOK1RsDzVpfA1fw_sdZmdCZ0FX8NTvgQDDBU2cZ_Dxne-HKzIoWjWnV_WvJj2DVbLNrzEoEpAS1tbrces7Za43lRVmdKApM3ykJEFB4KDQZgrqkcGSRBlEm2V6tL9hQOk692V3gPEyd1A&sm=1) and the median_earnings [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dbjwsnjvapl6xhzy2vdf1/median_earnings.json?dl=0&oref=e&r=AAUZXYRxpKzM0a4Z7uA1FfnMFmRvvUqPiPxkKB4rcvXY9e3snQNdZB0YSl5Pes9vR3S09IcB5r7nRCwQN-lfQ6T53r_vM4_f_L5biclP0XpPgZFlPI-v0gsvYKftLhmkf5Y7TKzyzZUUhaSh-yHF9kiAzfF6xqwKVOlccxN6O8oQUA&sm=1).

And this is the version with d3.queue

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Choropleth Map of College Data</title>
<style>

.counties {
  fill: none;
}

.states {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var margin = {top: 10, right: 200, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;    
    
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var earnings = d3.map();

var path = d3.geo.path();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .rangeRound([600, 860]);

var color = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain([15000, 18000, 21000, 24000, 27000, 30000, 33000])    .range(['#f7fcfd','#e5f5f9','#ccece6','#99d8c9','#66c2a4','#41ae76','#238b45','#005824']);

d3.json("median_earnings.json", function loadjson(error, earnings) {
    if (error) throw error;
    earnings.forEach(function(d) {
            d.id = +d.id;
            d.median = +d.median_earnings;
            
    d3.json("us.json", function ready(error, us) {
        if (error) throw error;
    
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "states")    
        .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke", "grey");
        
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .attr("class", "states")    
        .datum(earnings)    
        .attr("fill", function(d,i) { 
            return color(d[i].median);
            });
    });    
})
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the IDs on your files don't match.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I don't understand what you mean.